How to parse the text file using bash script
I am new to bash script. I need help in parsing a text file (say sample.txt) which contains the data like below
*AR   eth0      ethernet0
*A    eth1      ethernet1
      eth2      ethernet2
                ethernet3
*A     eth4      ethernet4
      T  E S T  ethernet5

I want the output like below
eth0
eth1
eth2

eth4
T  E S T

I have used below command, but it did not worked
sed 's/^ \{1,\}/SPACE_PLACEHOLDER/g' sample.txt | awk '{print $2}' | sed 's/SPACE_PLACEHOLDER/ /g'


Can you describe in words by what criteria the "columns" in the file should be split?

the provided sample does not appear to be tab-delimited, nor does it appear to be based on fixed-width column definitions (eg, ethernet4 is not left-aligned with the other ethernetX strings); we also don't have any information on the possible formats of the various columns, eg, if the first column exists will it always be a string that starts with a * and contain no spaces?  will the 3rd (last) column always start with the string ethernet and contain no white space? if you say no to either question then consider providing a more representative set of data

I am sorry, may be I didn't give the complete information.
Actually, I wanted to parse the output of "connmanctl services" which outputs as in above sample format.

FYI (grep-or-sed-or-awk) | (grep-or-sed-or-awk) is an antipattern. Whatever you're doing with a pipeline like that can be done with awk alone (and sometimes sed alone). See https://porkmail.org/era/unix/award#grep for more info.
Using any POSIX sed given any type of horizontal spaces (e.g. blanks and/or tabs) in your input:
$ sed 's/^[^[:space:]]*[[:space:]]*//; s/[[:space:]]*[^[:space:]]*$//' file
eth0
eth1
eth2

eth4
T  E S T

and with GNU sed:
$ sed 's/^\S*\s*//; s/\s*\S*$//' file
eth0
eth1
eth2

eth4
T  E S T

and similarly with any POSIX awk:
$ awk '{sub(/^[^[:space:]]*[[:space:]]*/,""); sub(/[[:space:]]*[^[:space:]]*$/,"")} 1' file
eth0
eth1
eth2

eth4
T  E S T

and so on...
If the tool you're using isn't POSIX compliant in regards to supporting character classes then just replace each [[:space:]] with [ \t] and [^[:space:]] with [^ \t] or similar.

for the example provided (which is a mess), try the following
cat /tmp/praveen.awk
NF == 3 || NF == 2 { print NF == 3 ? $2 : $1; next }
NF >3 { sub(/^\s+/,""); sub($NF, "" ); print $0 }

gawk -f /tmp/praveen.awk /tmp/praveen.txt
eth0
eth1
eth2
eth4
T  E S T  

As always, test/check/double-check any/all suggested examples

this is missing the empty line for ethernet3

Indeed, deliberately so, the code is simple enough for the requestor to complete.

You should mention that requires GNU awk (or some other that supports this no0n-POSIX extension) for \s. Regarding sub($NF,...) - it's almost never safe to use a field in the regexp part of any command as it'd fail if a string in the input matches that regexp earlier/differently than expected so sub($NF, "" ) should be sub(/\S+$/, "" ) to work for any contents of $NF, Try both if $NF contained .* or eth to see what I mean.

NF == 3 || NF == 2 { print NF == 3 ? $2 : $1; next } would be more concise as NF == 3 || NF == 2 { print $(NF-1) } (or even NF ~ /^[23]$/ { print $(NF-1) }). You don't need the next.

Note well the suggestions/feedback recommended by @ed morton - , also, this is is the version of gawk used - GNU Awk 5.0.1, API: 2.0 (GNU MPFR 4.0.2, GNU MP 6.2.0)
Copyright (C) 1989, 1991-2019 Free Software Foundation. on Linux Mint 20.1
